# Using MarkMonitor.com for DNS Management Services

Tags: domain-name-system, monitoring, dns-hosting

Have you ever used [MarkMonitor](http://markmonitor.com/) for DNS management? I've just started dealing with them recently for a customer who uses them as an aggregator to purchase their domain names and it seems to me that their service is not really up to standards.

I guess I'm curious if I'm the only one who's had a bad experience with them or are their tools and services really a little bit crude and outdated?

Also, I'm interested if you could suggest any alternative services for Domain Name management and DNS hosting that are at least decent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using [EveryDNS.NET](http://www.everydns.net) for several years with positive results.  While a free service they do accept donations to help keep everything running along.

> We provide static DNS services as well
>   as many advanced services such as
>   Dynamic DNS resolution, Secondary
>   service, AXFR service, and domain2web
>   redirection. Of course, our primary
>   service is free DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm going to give EveryDNS.NET a try..

Answer (score 0):

I've never used MarkMonitor so I can't speak to that. I've used DynDNS for dns management (and services) for years now. Their service is great and they're offering more and more services each year. The prices on *most* of their services are fair, while others (like domain name purchasing) seem a little disproportionate to other vendors. Overall, I wouldn't hesitate recommending them for their DNS services. I have not used *all* of their products, but I have used their recursive DNS, mailhop and dynamic DNS services.

Comment: I found DynDNS exceptionally expensive for hosting multiple zones. We pay $60/year for 10 zones with our current provider. DynDNS wanted to charge almost 10x that amount...

Comment: Well, they could be *extremely* expensive in comparison but I haven't had any problems with their service over the years so I consider it to be a fair trade. Who do you use for your DNS for such a low rate? I'd be willing to switch pending a number of factors of course.

Answer (score 0):

I have used (and continue to use) MarkMonitor to administrate my company's roughly 1400 domains. I can not recall any incident of "bad service" in the 3 years that we've used their service, and I am the primary person that purchases and administrates all of our domains.

I would suggest discussing whatever issue you've got with your account rep, and if need be, replace that person.

Comment: You must be very lucky.  In the span of about a year that I've dealt with MarkMonitor I've had a very unpleasant experience.  A single example is the fact that in order to change my password I have to contact the account rep.  Simply unacceptable!